# How to interpret Rails stats outputs table data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to interpret Rails stats?
[image]

What does the following columns means?

- Lines
- LOC
- M/C
- LOC/M

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When looking at the output from rake stats, there are a few important bits of information that you should look at first, and that are all in the final summary line, in this case:

- Lines of Code (Excluding test code): 337
- Lines of Test Code: 406
- Code to Test Ratio: 1:1.2

A Code to Test Ratio of 1:1.2 is pretty good. 
For example, a Code to Test Ratio of 1 to 4 is somewhat ridiculous. Its incredibly high, and when you see something like this, its important to ask why? That’s pretty much the entire usefulness of the output of rake stats as a metric. Here are some -personal- guidelines:

- Anything less than 1:1 the code probably lacks sufficient tests.
- Anything more than 1:2 is suspect to questioning, but upon investigation could be found to be perfectly reasonable.

There are a few other nice things in the output from rake stats that are helpful for a birds eye view of the application. For example, I can tell that your application has 6 models and 5 controllers.

Hope that helped.

Comment: What's the diff between `Lines` and `LOC`?

Comment: 'Lines' would related to any line (i.e. full-line comments or blank lines). LOCs are lines that actually have code on them. @LiXinyang